# What is wrong with the FAKE argument --listTargets?

Tags: f#, f#-fake

According to the FAKE documentation you can list all existing targets in your build file by executing FAKE with the argument --listTargets (or alternatively -lt):

```
> ./build.sh --listTargets
```

build.sh is a wrapper script from ProjectScaffold.

https://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/specifictargets.html

My version of FAKE is:

```
> ./build.sh --version
FakePath: ...
FAKE - F# Make "4.16.1"
```

When I run the listTarget command I get a strange output:

```
Error parsing command line arguments.  You have a mistake in your args, or are using the pre-2.1.8 argument style:
Exception Message:unrecognized argument: '--listTargets'.
```

At the end of the error message I get the information I wanted:

```
Attempting to run with pre-version 2.18 argument style, for backwards compat.
Available targets:
  - Clean 
     Depends on: []
  - Build 
     Depends on: ["Clean"]
  - CopyBinaries 
     Depends on: ["Build"]
  - RunTests 
     Depends on: ["CopyBinaries"]
  - Default 
     Depends on: ["RunTests"]
```

From the error message I get the impression that something changed in version 2.1.8 according to the argument style.

My question: What is the correct way to list all existing targets with FAKE?

Here is the complete output:

```
> ./build.sh --listTargets
No version specified. Downloading latest stable.
Paket.exe 2.47.1.0 is up to date.
Paket version 2.47.1.0
0 seconds - ready.
Error parsing command line arguments.  You have a mistake in your args, or are using the pre-2.1.8 argument style:
Exception Message:unrecognized argument: '--listTargets'.

    --envvar [-ev] <string> <string>: Set environment variable <name> <value>. Supports multiple.
    --envflag [-ef] <string>: Set environment variable flag <name> 'true'. Supports multiple.
    --logfile [-lf] <string>: Build output log file path.
    --printdetails [-pd]: Print details of FAKE's activity.
    --version [-v]: Print FAKE version information.
    --fsiargs [-fa] <string> ...: Pass args after this switch to FSI when running the build script.
    --boot [-b] <string> ...: Boostrapp your FAKE script.
    --break [-br]: Pauses FAKE with a Debugger.Break() near the start
    --single-target [-st]: Runs only the specified target and not the dependencies.
    --nocache [-nc]: Disables caching of compiled script
    --help [-h|/h|/help|/?]: display this list of options.

**************************************************
Type: System.ArgumentException
HResult: -2147024809
Source: Argu
TargetSite: Nessos.Argu.ParseResults`1[Cli+FakeArg] Nessos-Argu-IExiter-Exit[ParseResults`1](System.String, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[System.Int32])

StackTrace
**************************************************

  at Nessos.Argu.ExceptionExiter.Nessos-Argu-IExiter-Exit[b] (System.String msg, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 _arg1) <0x30ab2b8 + 0x00027> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Nessos.Argu.ArgumentParser`1[Template].Parse (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 inputs, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 xmlConfigurationFile, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 errorHandler, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 ignoreMissing, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 ignoreUnrecognized, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 raiseOnUsage) <0x2d47288 + 0x00332> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cli.parsedArgsOrEx (IEnumerable`1 args) <0x70a390 + 0x000cb> in <filename unknown>:0 
Attempting to run with pre-version 2.18 argument style, for backwards compat.
Available targets:
  - Clean 
     Depends on: []
  - Build 
     Depends on: ["Clean"]
  - CopyBinaries 
     Depends on: ["Build"]
  - RunTests 
     Depends on: ["CopyBinaries"]
  - Default 
     Depends on: ["RunTests"]
```

**Update**

I've just found a GitHub issue which reference my problem some how but I can make no sense of it:

https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/1082

Comment: I think it is probably an issue in how the `build.sh` wrapper passes the arguments to FAKE rather than in FAKE itself

Comment: @tomas-petricek I've checked that: Same result with 'mono ./packages/build/FAKE/tools/FAKE.exe --listTargets'

Comment: Yup, I have same issue.
EDIT: dropping "target" works: 'fake Mytarget', not 'fake "target=Mytarget" '